# If specific text founded remove text between specific text in python

Tags: python, string, text, between

I have a data with many lines and which look like this:

```
<br>&emsp;&emsp;<font size="4">&bull;</font>&emsp; Closed Point 3<br>&emsp;&emsp;<font size="4">&bull;</font>&emsp; Opened Shape<br>
```

I'd like to search for word "Point" in lines and if it finds it remove only this part:

```
<br>&emsp;&emsp;<font size="4">&bull;</font>&emsp; Closed Point 3
```

So 
it will leave only:

```
<br>&emsp;&emsp;<font size="4">&bull;</font>&emsp; Opened Shape<br>
```

Im stuck over here:

```
with open(input, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    with open(output, 'w') as w:
        for line in lines:
            if 'Point' in line:
```

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate string.replace; here is a description:

```
string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])
```

> Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

and consider what would happen if "new" was an empty string.

Comment: what if i have not "Closed Point" but instead "Opened Point" ? should i put many ifs replacing to empty " " ?

Comment: If the text you wish to change varies, a regular expression substitution is probably what you need. In that case you could read up on [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) (again setting the `repl` parameter to an empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Look no further than the string replace method.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

`line = line.replace('Closed Point 3','Opened Shape')`

You don't even need the if statement as the replace function will return the original string if no match is found.

Comment: but i have such line: <br>&emsp;&emsp;<font size="4">&bull;</font>&emsp; Closed Point 3<br>&emsp;&emsp;<font size="4">&bull;</font>&emsp; Opened Shape<br>

Comment: His input string already has "Opened Shape" (need to scroll right).

Comment: i guess i'd need find a way to delete some text between <br> and <br> but the <br> on the end must stay. I dont think that replace function will help.

Comment: Ah, yes, my misread on the long line... however, If you want to delete the text, just replace with an empty string... as Mark's answer suggested

"line = line.replace('Closed Point 3','')"

Comment: yeah, but i want to replace every line (i have many of them) which have word "Point" and only delete the part between <br> and <br> but <br> must stay on the end of the line